# table moviesTable has no column named name

Tags: flutter

I try to create database to save a list of movies name 
and when I create databasehelper class and try to use saveMovie() method in the main
I got this proplem

this is my DatabaseHelper Class :
.......................................

```
   class DatabaseHelper {
  final String moviesTable = "moviesTable";
  final String idColumn = "id";
  final String namesColumn = "name";
  final String descriptionsColumn = "description";
  final String ratesColumn = "rate";

  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = DatabaseHelper.internal();
  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;
  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async{
    if(_db != null){
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();
  initDb() async{
    Directory fileDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(fileDirectory.path,"maindb.db");
    var maindb = await openDatabase(path,version: 1,onCreate: _onCreate);
    return maindb;
  }
  void _onCreate(Database db,int newVersion) async{
    await db.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE $moviesTable($idColumn INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $namesColumn TEXT, $descriptionsColumn TEXT, $ratesColumn TEXT)");
  }

  Future<int> saveMovie(Movie movie) async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.insert("$moviesTable", movie.toMap());
    return res;
  }

  Future colse() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

and this Movie class

```
class Movie{
  String _name;
  String _description;
  String _rate;
  int _id;

  Movie(this._name, this._description, this._rate);

  Movie.map(dynamic obj){
    this._name = obj["name"];
    this._description = obj["description"];
    this._rate = obj["rate"];
    this._id = obj["id"];
  }

  String get name => _name;
  String get description => _description;
  String get rate => _rate;
  int get id => _id;

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["name"] = _name;
    map["description"] = _description;
    map["rate"] = _rate;
    if(id != null){
      map["id"] = _id;
    }
    return map;
  }

  Movie.formMap(Map<String,dynamic> map){
    this._name = map["name"];
    this._description = map["description"];
    this._rate = map["rate"];
    this._id = map["id"];

  }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happened ?
.....................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested, your code works fine. 
You can copy paste run full code below 
When first time you run this in Emulator, the table had created. and it will not create again even you change table schema 
Change `maindb.db` to another name like `maindb1.db` will work 
`String path = join(fileDirectory.path,"maindb.db");`

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class DatabaseHelper {
  final String moviesTable = "moviesTable";
  final String idColumn = "id";
  final String namesColumn = "name";
  final String descriptionsColumn = "description";
  final String ratesColumn = "rate";

  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = DatabaseHelper.internal();
  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;
  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async{
    if(_db != null){
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();
  initDb() async{
    Directory fileDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(fileDirectory.path,"maindb.db");
    var maindb = await openDatabase(path,version: 1,onCreate: _onCreate);
    return maindb;
  }
  void _onCreate(Database db,int newVersion) async{
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE $moviesTable($idColumn INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $namesColumn TEXT, $descriptionsColumn TEXT, $ratesColumn TEXT)");
  }

  Future<int> saveMovie(Movie movie) async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.insert("$moviesTable", movie.toMap());
    print("saved");
    return res;
  }

  Future colse() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.close();
  }
}

class Movie{
  String _name;
  String _description;
  String _rate;
  int _id;

  Movie(this._name, this._description, this._rate);

  Movie.map(dynamic obj){
    this._name = obj["name"];
    this._description = obj["description"];
    this._rate = obj["rate"];
    this._id = obj["id"];
  }

  String get name => _name;
  String get description => _description;
  String get rate => _rate;
  int get id => _id;

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["name"] = _name;
    map["description"] = _description;
    map["rate"] = _rate;
    if(id != null){
      map["id"] = _id;
    }
    return map;
  }

  Movie.formMap(Map<String,dynamic> map){
    this._name = map["name"];
    this._description = map["description"];
    this._rate = map["rate"];
    this._id = map["id"];

  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      var movie =
      Movie("a","b","c");
      var dbHelper = DatabaseHelper();
      dbHelper.saveMovie(movie);

      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```